# get value in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

I want to get value from `NSDictionary`. I want to control "Code" key according to Code key, I will get datum values. I get error message When I try different methods.

ERROR MESSAGE

> 2011-08-11 12:45:21.549 AOK[6312:207] -[__NSArrayM
>   getObjects:andKeys:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5e138b0
>   2011-08-11 12:45:21.550 AOK[6312:207] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM
>   getObjects:andKeys:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x5e138b0'
>   *** Call stack at first throw:

NSDictionary

```
(
        {
        Omschrijving = "ADDD";
        Ophaaldata =         {
            Datum =             (
                "2011-07-04",
                "2011-07-11",
                "2011-07-18",
                "2011-07-25"
            );
        };
    },
        {
        Omschrijving = "BBBB";
        Ophaaldata =         {
            Datum =             (
                "2011-07-05",
                "2011-07-12",
                "2011-07-19",
                "2011-07-26"
            );
        };
    },
        {
        Omschrijving = "KKKK";
        Ophaaldata =         {
            Datum =             (
                "2011-07-07",
                "2011-07-14",
                "2011-07-21",
                "2011-07-28"
            );
        };
    },
        {
        Omschrijving = "LLLLL";
        Ophaaldata =         {
            Datum =             (
                "2011-07-01",
                "2011-07-08",
                "2011-07-15",
                "2011-07-22",
                "2011-07-29"
            );
        };
    },
        {
        Omschrijving = "MMMMM";
        Ophaaldata =         {
            Datum =             (
                "2011-07-01",
                "2011-07-15",
                "2011-07-29"
            );
        };
    },
        {
        Code = POP;
        Omschrijving = "FFFF";
        Ophaaldata =         {
            Datum = "2011-07-12";
        };
    },
        {
        Code = 00;
        Omschrijving = "SSSS";
        Ophaaldata =         {
            Datum =             (
                "2011-07-14",
                "2011-07-27"
            );
        };
    },
        {
        Code = 01;
        Omschrijving = "CCCCC";
        Ophaaldata =         {
            Datum =             (
                "2011-07-06",
                "2011-07-20"
            );
        };
    }
)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you display is an NSArray of NSDictionaries, each containing an NSString with the description (Omschrijving) and an NSDictionary (Ophaaldata) with one key (Datum), which is an array of dates. If you send `Objects:andKeys:` to an NSArray, it won't work.

These are a few examples of how you can get at the individual items:

```
NSArray          *dicts = ...; // wherever you get the array
  NSDictionary   *mijnDict = [dicts objectAtIndex: n];
    NSString     *omschrijving = [mijnDict objectForKey: @"Omschrijving"];
    NSDictionary *ophaaldata = [mijnDict objectForkey: @"Ophaaldata"];
      NSArray    *datum = [ophaaldata objectForkey: @"Datum"];
        NSString *eersteDatum = [datum objectAtIndex: 0];
```

These are only examples of how you can address the items. But this is the structure your output shows. Anything else would be useless, anyway, since a dictionary can only contain each key once. I formatted the code a little, so you can see the structure a bit better.

Answer (score 2):

During Response Value of lines keep in mind

```
{ .......... } indicates dictionary.
(............) indicates array.
Dictionary always have key with it like somename = "value in it", .......
Array has value seperated by comma like a , b , c .....
Now it is possible it may have array into dictionary like { somekey = ( a,b,c) } and vice versa
```

Answer (score 1):

```
reason: '-[__NSArrayM getObjects:andKeys:]:
```

Are you *sure* you have an `NSDictionary` and not an `NSArray`?

Comment: Yes I use NSDictionary. I get This value step by step